# Change * wildcard string in css

Tags: css

I need to replace a wildcard string i.e.: a dash (-) with another symbol

I know the following can replace the whole string in a

```
.<tag>:after {
   content: "new content"
}
```

but I need something like

```
.<tag>:after {
   content: replace("-", "$")
}
```

This is just vanilla css - preprocessors are not available.

To be honest I need to convert a string list into a list like in a tag in confluence through a css macros - so I don't have access to the source code.

For example: `"soccer - basketball - tennis"` `into "soccer | basketball | tennis"`, or

```
"soccer
basketball 
tennis"
```

Comment: why css? this seems like something javascript would be optimal for

Comment: @depperm its not available in confluence

Comment: Not possible with CSS unless those words are *separate* tags